# how to invoke a specific controller action in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am very new to Laravel. I created new Controller as

```
class ContactController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        die("X");
    }
}
```

And in the `routes.php` I wrote

```
Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');
```

I think hitting the following url the "X" must be printed. But it says "Not Found" error.

```
http://localhost/lapp/public/contact/index
```

What thing I am missing? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the apache module_rewrite is not activated. Activate it. It will surely work.

Answer (score -1):

Your guess is right. But the problem is with you URL.
it should be `http://localhost/lapp/public/contact`

Alternatively you can use `php artisan serve` command to start a server which would start the server on something like `http://localhost:8080` Then you can access the URL like: `http://localhost:8080/contact`

Comment: still can't invoke. the port 8000 wont help